# Why do cathode rays bend towards a positively charged plate? Please be a bit elaborate in the answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I need help in this quite basic question. Your answers should be  bit elaborate and make the concept clear to understand.

Comment: for a homework question you should give us your explanation and highlight where you need a clarification.

Comment: Hi Yogeswari and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest analysis is to assume that you have two parallel plates one with a positive charge and the other with a negative charge arranged so the electric field between the plates is approximately uniform.

Imagine a beam of negatively charged cathode rays coming in horizontally from the left between the parallel and the positive plate at the bottom.

You now have a situation which is essentially the same as the analysis of a projectile thrown horizontally in the Earth's gravitational field with no air resistance present.
In that case the motion of the projectile can be analysed in term of its constant velocity horizontal motion as there is no horizontal force and it constant acceleration vertical motion the constant force being the weight of the projectile.

So for the cathode rays their motion horizontally is a constant velocity as the force due to the charged plates only acts downwards, there is no horizontal component of force.
The cathode rays accelerate vertically downwards under the influence of the constant downward force downwards on them due to the electric field produced by the charged plates.

So the horizontal displacement $x$ after a time $t$ is given by $x = v_{ho} t$ where $v_{ho}$ is the constant horizontal velocity.
The vertical displacement $y$ of the cathode rays is $y=\frac 1 2 a t^2$ where $a$ is the constant downward acceleration of the cathode rays.

From this you can say that $x \propto y^2$ which is the equation of a parabola and that is the path taken by the cathode rays, the same shape as that of a projectile in the Earth's gravitational field.
The cathode rays move at constant speed horizontally but faster and faster towards the positively charged plate.

Answer (score 0):

The trajectory of a thrown ball is a curve with the concave side pointed at the center of the earth.   This is even true of the orbit of a satellite, or Luna.
That is because the ball is attracted to the center of the earth, by gravity.
Cathode rays are streams of negatively charged particles, and they are attracted by positive charge.   Unless some other force is acting on the cathode ray,
it will follow a curved path, with the positive charge on the concave side of the curve.   Classic (cathode-ray tube) televisions used magnetic fields to
cause curvature of the cathode ray path; that uses a different set of laws entirely (force depending not just on charge, but velocity).

Comment: So I guess I only imagined the scan plates on CRTs?

Comment: Oscilloscopes have electrostatic deflection, but not television or computer monitors.  Magnetic deflection is suitable for resonant tricks that make it more efficient for repetitive sweep operation, while oscilloscopes are used to display X and Y coordinates that aren't as predictable in time.